# User cannot see view, only sees tables

Tags: privileges, database-administration, netezza

These are the object privileges for a user on a netezza database. It says (S)elect, but the user cannot see views, only tables. Why is that?

```
Object Privileges
    (L)ist (S)elect (I)nsert (U)pdate (D)elete (T)runcate (L)ock
    (A)lter (D)rop a(B)ort (L)oad (G)enstats Gr(O)om (E)xecute
    Label-A(C)cess Label-(R)estrict Label-E(X)pand Execute-(A)s
Administration Privilege
    (D)atabase (G)roup (U)ser (S)chema (T)able T(E)mp E(X)ternal
    Se(Q)uence S(Y)nonym (V)iew (M)aterialized View (I)ndex (B)ackup
    (R)estore va(C)uum (S)ystem (H)ardware (F)unction (A)ggregate
    (L)ibrary (P)rocedure U(N)fence (S)ecurity Scheduler (R)ule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIST permission allows you to see an object, and a TABLE is a different object class than a VIEW.

If you want a user to see a view then you must grant LIST on that view (or the general object class of VIEW). Being granted LIST or SELECT on a table (or the object class of TABLE) has nothing to do with whether a user can see a VIEW.

If you had two views called VIEW_1 and VIEW_2 you could either do something like:

```
GRANT LIST, SELECT on VIEW_1, VIEW_2 to USER1234
```

or if you wanted them to have those permissions for all views in the database scope you grant to VIEW which is a reference to the object class for all views.

```
GRANT LIST, SELECT on VIEW to USER1234
```

Similarly you could grant to TABLE (which represents the table object class), and that would apply to all tables in the scope.

Comment: what is the general object class of view?

Comment: VIEW is the object class for all views, and TABLE is the same for all tables.  Added samples to the answer.